# Facebook Login not return email

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

I've implemented Facebook Login on Android as [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) recommends. However I didn't get email to some specific users, follow implementation:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new OnGraphApiCallback());
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields","id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

After that, I was checking GraphAPI to know if I could get the email of these users that I couldn't retrieve previously when I was using Android implementation. Than I didn't get email too using GraphAPI.

I checked these users and I was sure that they didn't confirm their email on Facebook, because I couldn't get their email using Facebook SDK or [GraphAPI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api).

In the end, I chose to handle this via front-end(Android), when the user didn't confirm his/her email.

Would you think this solution is suitable?
Which solution would you choose?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood your question correctly, if I misunderstand, sorry.
E-mail fields are only retrieved when users sign up for email or have an email added to their Facebook account.
For example, if the user registered with a phone number, the value returned by the "email" field will be null because the user does not have an email associated with his facebook account.